# How do I close the client connection in a uhttpsharp request handler?

Tags: .net, vb.net

The documentation in the uHttpServer repository does not have a complete example for request handling.

I am trying to reply with arbitrary data to an http request using a uHttpServer.HttpServer instance.

This is what I came up with by looking at the example solution.

```
  Dim hs As New uhttpsharp.HttpServer(New uhttpsharp.RequestProviders.HttpRequestProvider())
    hs.Use(New uhttpsharp.Listeners.TcpListenerAdapter(New System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(Net.IPAddress.Any, 12345)))
    hs.Use(Function(context, nxt)
        Dim newBody = $"You asked for: {context.Request.Uri}"
        context.Response = New HttpResponse(HttpResponseCode.Ok, newBody, False)
        Return next()
    End Function)
    hs.Start()
    Console.ReadLine() 
    hs.Dispose()
```

The problem now it's that by inspecting with an interception proxy the request stays pending forever.

Comment: Questions that you intend to answer yourselkf must still meet the quality guidelines here, and this one does not. Please [edit] it to make it an acceptable, properly asked question instead of a *plz givez me teh codez* question that you're answering.

Comment: I expanded the question with the original context.

Comment: No, you edited the question to include the same code that is in your answer. That is not a question. You need to ask a **specific, clear question** that represents the problem you're solving with your answer below. Pree-posting the answer in the question does not do so.

Comment: I had figured the solution by the time I wrote the question, so chronologically the code is originated in the question. I omitted the solution from the code to reconstruct the original situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. Since I think it may be useful to others I put it here. Due to how the request handling is implemented the library expects a completed task (available with `Task.Factory.GetCompleted`) in order to properly close the connection with the client.

```
    Dim hs As New uhttpsharp.HttpServer(New uhttpsharp.RequestProviders.HttpRequestProvider())
    hs.Use(New uhttpsharp.Listeners.TcpListenerAdapter(New System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(Net.IPAddress.Any, 12345)))
    hs.Use(Function(context, nxt)
        Dim newBody = $"You asked for: {context.Request.Uri}"
        context.Response = New HttpResponse(HttpResponseCode.Ok, newBody, False)
        Return Task.Factory.GetCompleted()
    End Function)
    hs.Start()
    Console.ReadLine() 
    hs.Dispose()
```